# Replacing exist in SQL query for time optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have the following SQL that works spot on but with bigger data set has proven to time out

```
    insert into RolePermissions
    select      
        [ID],
        R.[ContractManager],
        @ActionType,
        null
    from Roles R
    where not exists
    (
        select 'x'
        from RolePermissions
        where [RoleID] = R.[ID]
        and [ActionType] = @ActionType
    );
```

Can anybody suggest a way to optimise this ?

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables? Can you post the definitions of the indexes, along with the query plan on [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Why do you think you can optimize it`? THis is NOT a query. THe INSERT part may just take ages, not the select part. That will require more IO capacity and a larger timeout. That is the reality. Provide at least a query plan.

Answer (score 1):

For the `NOT EXISTS`, be sure you have an index on `RolePermissions(RoleID, ActionType)`.

Comment: is there a way i can do the same with Joins ?

Comment: @UncleDaveIsWatching . . . Add the index.  The `JOIN`s probably won't help much with performance if you don't have the right indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into Left outer join to see the performance benifit:

```
insert into RolePermissions
    select      
        [ID],
        R.[ContractManager],
        @ActionType,
        null
    from Roles R left outer join RolePermissions R on (roleid = R.id)
    WHERE R.ID IS NULL
    AND [ActionType] = @ActionType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First of all, you might want to make sure that `ActionType` is numeric, because numeric searches are quicker. If you have some text as value there, then create a table to store action types, which would have an id and the text value and in `RolePermissions` store only the id reference.

Next, create an index for (RoleID, ActionType) for `RolePermissions`.

If it is still slow, then create a task that is repeatedly executed, which loads the records which are missing and inserts them and increase the timeout limit if needed.

If all fails, then you can create triggers on `Roles` which would create the records in `RolePermissions` that you need. Switch off temporarily any application/access to the database, temporarily increase the timeout limit, execute the script that you have, revert all temporary actions which enabled you for this and from there on you will not need this type of insert, because the trigger will ensure that `RolePermissions` is maintained.